# How to use onChange event to detect deleted sheet with a Google Sheets Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

onChange event has the "REMOVED_ROW" type for a SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder

However, nowhere in the documentation do I see a way to see which sheet was removed from the event. Is there a way to get the deleted sheet with this event?

Comment: If there isn't API support for getting that name, you'll have to use a combination of cache and a second trigger function that populates the cache. In your cache step, log the sheet names. Then just keep checking the current names against the cache names.

Comment: Unfortunately, ``onChange()`` cannot retrieve removing sheets as an event. This has also already said by Rubén. So for example, how about using Push Notifications of Drive API? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push Using this event, it compares before and after the number of sheets. Although this way is almost the real time event, it might be a bit difficult for the setting than tehhowch's proposal.

Answer (score 0):

The change event for most of the change types doesn't include a property that could be used to identify the inserted, removed sheets among other changes. In order to identify which sheet was affected we have to keep a list of spreadsheet sheets to compare with the current sheets collection. For that we could use the Properties service that could be safer than use a sheet as it could be deleted too.