# Capture Google Spreadsheet's Delete and Copy Sheet Event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am writing some data in google spreadsheets. For each sheet I am creating a file in drive and storing few information. If user right clicks at any sheet and clicks delete or duplicate, I want to capture delete and duplicate event so that I can delete or copy the stored file data rather than creating again.

I tried the documentation of google spreadsheet api's but didn't any event that I can override to delete file created by me for particular sheet, when user is deleting that sheet.

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: This has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666125/how-to-use-onchange-event-to-detect-deleted-sheet-with-a-google-sheets-apps-scri). There doesn't seem to be an easy solution.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.